# How do I increase my range from the space walk?

Tags: broken-age

[image]

My air tube is tying me down!

How do I extend or cut the hose so that I can jump higher/longer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Get the knife from the kitchen to cut the cable.

Answer (score 0):

with the knife from the kitchen its on the side.